# How to store user selection from custom application page?

Tags: application-pages

We have created application page in SharePoint 2010 to show a asp:grid with some calculated data. The columns are configured and user can select columns from checkbox list. The question is, We want to store the user selected columns and show it back when user revisit the page. What will be the best way to save user selection and retrieve it back?

Answer (score 0):

One way could be to store the user preferences in a Custom SharePoint list and retrieve it from the list when user visits the page.